# Regular Expression to extract multiple values from a delimited string

Tags: regex, awk

I want to extract both **i-name** & **ipaddress** from the below string (where `;` is delimiter)

**INPUT:**

```
i-03ghijklmn345;abc;xyz;pqr;null;abc;null;null;null;disabled;/dev/sda1;abc;abc: User initiated shutdown;abc;abc;vpc-abc;**192.186.40.255**;abc  /dev/sda1   vol-abc 2017-15-14T12:04:17.000z
```

I was able to retrieve the **ipaddress** only from this using `([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}` but I need both strings in one line

**OUTPUT:**

```
i-03ghijklmn345;192.186.40.255
```

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: a) Welcome to SO, b) Reformat your question, c) Better use some splitting on `;` instead.

Comment: Hello i was able to retrieve the ip address only from this table like giving ([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3} but i wanted to get the details of both i-03ghijklmn345 & 192.186.40.255 in 1 line. and its seperated from ;

Comment: How is your records separated? Or is it just one line? Does your records follow a similar pattern?

Comment: It is seperated by similar pattern only same as semicolon in the middle

Comment: I tried to edit the question based on comments, feel free to edit if I've made some mistake... also, does `cut -d';' -f1,17` or `awk -F';' '{print $1, $17}'` answer your question?

Comment: Next time, when you ask a question, make sure you put your efforts in the question itself and not in comments. Questions without code to solve it may attract negative criticism in the form of down-votes.

Comment: Alright Thanks will do that hereafter

Answer (score 1):

No need for AWK. Use `grep`:

```
# Partial Bash script
I_NAME=$(cat your_file | grep -Po 'i-\w+')
IP_ADDR=$(cat your_file | grep -Po '\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}')
```

The RegEx is between the single quotes in the commands above.

Comment: Why not `awk` replace `cat|grep` here? That would be more efficient imho.

Comment: @sjsam because I don't know `awk`, sadly.

Comment: How to use it together in 1 expression so that i can extract exact value

Comment: @Tejas  What do you mean by exact value? In the question mention the required output format. Also please reply to my comment to the question.

Comment: Apologies for not giving properly.

Comment: Exact Value means i-03ghijklmn345;192.186.40.255 should be extracted from the line together.I need a awk expression grep dosent work.

Comment: I have proposed a `awk` solution please let me know if it works for you~

Comment: Thank Allan works fine for me and thanks for the solution and explaination as well

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `awk` solution and for a **bit of diversity** you can use the following commands:

```
iName=$(awk 'BEGIN{RS=";"}/^i-\w+/{print $1; exit}' inputFile)
ipAddress=$(awk 'BEGIN{RS=";"}/([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}/{print $1; exit}' inputFile) 
echo $iName 
echo $ipAddress
```

**output:**

i-03ghijklmn345
192.186.40.255

**explanations:**

- `BEGIN{RS=";"}` you defined `;` as record separator
- `/^i-\w+/{print $1; exit}` when you reach the i-name it will be printed and **the process will stop at that point and will not continue analyzing the input string**
- `/([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}/{print $1; exit}` works the same way to extract the IP address.
- finally you assign the result to the 2 variables and display their content or do whatever you want with them.
- change the `inputFile` with what fit your needs.

If you want to put it in one variable use the following `awk` command:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=";"}/^i-\w+/{printf $1;}/([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}/{print ";"$1;exit}' inputFile;                                          
i-03ghijklmn345;192.186.40.255
```

**TESTED:**

[image]

Comment: Hmm.. Your pattern for IP address may be refined

Comment: I have used the one proposed and that's true that there are better regex for ip address

Answer (score 1):

Considering your pattern, the first field is some sort of an id and so it is inappropriate for an id to contain an asterisk(`*`). Also the ip address is always enclosed between asterisks(`*`). In that case below `awk` would also help.

```
$ cat 48437686
i03ghijklmn345;abc;xyz;pqr;null;abc;null;null;null;disabled;/dev/sda1;abc;abc: User initiated shutdown;abc;abc;vpc-abc;**192.186.40.255**;abc   /dev/sda1   vol-abc 2017-15-14T12:04:17.000z
$ awk -v RS=";" 'BEGIN{oldORS=ORS}NR==1 || /^\*\*.*\*\*$/{gsub(/*/,"");ORS=NR==1?";":oldORS;print}' 48437686
i03ghijklmn345;192.186.40.255
```

Answer (score 1):

With awk. Set input and output field separator to `;` and print columns 1 and 17:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {print $1,$17}' file
```

Output:

```
i-03ghijklmn345;192.186.40.255
```